# how to use a function pointer in a cast to another function pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers, function-prototypes

While working with very old minix sw (MINIX 1.5) I encountered weird function declarations; 1) the declaration of a function's prototype, and 2) the declaration of the function itself

```
/* in header file the prototype of a signal function, with my annotations */

     /*---is this some sort of casting ???---*/
             /*----two input arguments----*/
void (*signal(int sig,  void (*_func)(int) )  )  (int);

                        /*---func ptr---*/
```

I can only deduct a casting, but what is `casted` here and how would you describe the resulting function? The same definition is maintained in the code file, so we are definitely talking a function declaration, but its output is not clear to me. Refer to the next code snippet. Some reference to documentation is welcome.

```
/* in the code file */

PUBLIC void (*signal(int signr, void (*func)(int))) (int){
  void (*old) (int);

  /* there is more code, but not relevant for the problem */

return(old);
}
```

Comment: cdecl: "declare signal as function (int, pointer to function (int) returning void) returning pointer to function (int) returning void"

Comment: There is no casting involved here. You have a function that takes a function pointer and also returns a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would not advice to hide a pointer type in a typedef.
This might be one of the exceptions.

You can make your life easier:

```c
typedef void (*sig_func_type)(int);

sig_func_type signal(int sig, sig_func_type func);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no cast here.  What you have is a function that takes a function pointer as one of its arguments and returns a function pointer.

Linux uses a similar declaration, but the man page shows it using typedefs for the function pointers to make it more clear:

```
   typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

   sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

Answer (score 2):

In `void (*signal(int sig,  void (*_func)(int) )  )  (int);`, matching the first open parentheses with its close parentheses shows the form is `void (…)(int);`.

This declares a function with an `int` parameter and returning nothing (`void`).

Inside the parentheses, we have `*signal(int sig,  void (*_func)(int) )`. Again matching the first open parentheses to its close parentheses gives the form `*signal()`, so we see this is a function returning a pointer to the surrounding type, which we know from above is a function with an `int` parameter returning `void`.

Therefore `signal` is a function that returns a pointer to a function with an `int` parameter returning `void`.

Looking inside the parentheses after `signal`, we know these are the parameters to the function `signal`, and they are `int sig` and `void (*_func)(int)`.

`int sig` clearly declares an `int` parameter. `void (*_func)(int)` declares `(*_func)` to be a function taking an `int` parameter and returning `void`. Since `(*_func)` is a function, `_func` is a pointer to a function.

So the entire declaration declares `signal` to be a function that takes a first parameter that is an `int` and a second parameter that is a pointer to a function taking an `int` parameter and returning `void`, and `signal` returns a pointer to a function taking an `int` parameter and returning `void`.

If you call a function that takes an `int` parameter and returns `void` a “signal handler,” then `signal` is a function that takes an `int` and a pointer to a signal handler and that returns a pointer to a signal handler.